# Adding entries to an Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist

I am trying to compile the code that adds Address book entries into my array.  I have most of the driver program, which takes the input of first and last name, and then adds them, and also searches for certain values.  My problem is the code that adds a new entry- I am trying to add multiple strings as one entry in an address book, and then call addEntry, but I am getting the following errors...

C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:17: error: constructor SJAddressBook in class SJAddressBook cannot be applied to given types;
        aBook.add(new SJAddressBook());
                  ^
  required: String,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        aBook.get(count).addEntry();
                        ^
  symbol:   method addEntry()
  location: class SJAddressBook

C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        int foundIndex = abook.search(SJ);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable SJ
  location: class ScherpichJamesTest2

C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        int foundIndex = abook.search(SJ);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable abook
  location: class ScherpichJamesTest2

C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
            SJ.get(foundIndex).display();
            ^
  symbol:   variable SJ
  location: class ScherpichJamesTest2
.\SJAddressBook.java:27: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
    public static int search(ArrayListaBook);
                      ^
.\SJAddressBook.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        int choice=integer.parseInt(entry.nextLine());
                   ^
  symbol:   variable integer
  location: class SJAddressBook
.\SJAddressBook.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        for(SJAddressBook Address: aBook)
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable aBook
  location: class SJAddressBook
.\SJAddressBook.java:44: error: return outside method
                return aBook.IndexOf(Address);
                ^
.\SJAddressBook.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                if(value.equalisIgnoreCase(Address.LAST))
                        ^
  symbol:   method equalisIgnoreCase(String)
  location: variable value of type String
.\SJAddressBook.java:48: error: return outside method
                return aBook.IndexOf(Address);
                ^
.\SJAddressBook.java:53: error: return outside method
        return -1;
        ^
12 errors

Here is my main method class

```
{

public static void main(String[] args)

{
    ArrayList<SJAddressBook> aBook = new ArrayList<SJAddressBook>();
    for (int count =0;count <3;count ++)
    {

    aBook.add(new SJAddressBook());
    aBook.get(count).addEntry();
    System.out.println();


    }

    int foundIndex = abook.search(SJ);

    System.out.println();

    if (foundIndex > -1)

        SJ.get(foundIndex).display();

    else

        System.out.println("No Entry Found");

}
```

}

//And my driver class

```
public class SJAddressBook                  //start class definition
{
static String FIRST;
private String LAST;

public SJAddressBook(String first, String last)
{
    Scanner entry = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter First Name: ");
    FIRST = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Last Name: ");
    LAST = entry.nextLine();
}
public static int search(ArrayList<SJAddressBook>aBook);
{
    Scanner entry = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("1. First Name");
    System.out.println("2. Last Name");

    System.out.print("Please Enter Field to Search: ");
    int choice=integer.parseInt(entry.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter value to search for: ");
    String value=entry.nextLine();

    for(SJAddressBook Address: aBook)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(Address.FIRST))
            return aBook.IndexOf(Address);
            break;
            case 2:
            if(value.equalisIgnoreCase(Address.LAST))
            return aBook.IndexOf(Address);
            break;

        }
    }
    return -1;
}
public void display()
{
    System.out.println("First Name: "+this.FIRST);
    System.out.println("Last Name: "+this.LAST);
}
}
```

Comment: For the first error to fix:  Add a default constructor in your SJAddressBook class, if you have a constructor with arguments then JAVA does not create a default implicitly Or in your main method provide two String arguments while performing aBook.add(new SJAddressBook());

Comment: How do I fix an empty constructor, that has 2 arguments in the driver class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:17: error: constructor SJAddressBook in class SJAddressBook cannot be applied to given types; aBook.add(new SJAddressBook()); ^ required: String,String found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

- You are calling `new SJAddressBook ()` as an empty constructor and the only constructor for that class takes 2 arguments `SJAddressBook (String first, String last)`

> C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:18: error: cannot find symbol aBook.get (count).addEntry (); ^ symbol: method addEntry() location: class SJAddressBook

- there is no `addEntry ()` defined in the class **SJAddressBook**.  By calling **aBook.get (count)** you are returning the **SJAddressBook** at *get (count)* location.

> C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:24: error: cannot find symbol int foundIndex = abook.search (SJ); ^ symbol: variable SJ location: class ScherpichJamesTest2

- **SJ** is not defined anywhere (that I can see in your sample)

> C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:24: error: cannot find symbol int foundIndex = abook.search (SJ); ^ symbol: variable abook location: class ScherpichJamesTest2

- also not defined - it should be **aBook** not **abook**

> C:\Users\Scherpich\Desktop\Jim School\CS 219 Programming Fundamentals\Programs\ScherpichJamesTest2.java:30: error: cannot find symbol SJ.get (foundIndex).display (); ^ symbol: variable SJ location: class ScherpichJamesTest2

- again **SJ** is not defined

> .\SJAddressBook.java:27: error: missing method body, or declare abstract public static int search (ArrayListaBook); ^

- You have a ';' `public static int search(ArrayList<SJAddressBook>aBook);` that should not be there

> .\SJAddressBook.java:34: error: cannot find symbol int choice=integer.parseInt (entry.nextLine ()); ^ symbol: variable integer location: class SJAddressBook

- **Integer** not **integer**

> .\SJAddressBook.java:38: error: cannot find symbol for (SJAddressBook Address: aBook) ^ symbol: variable aBook location: class SJAddressBook

- Because of the previous error with the ';' the compiler thinks this is a *static code block* and thinks aBook is not defined

> .\SJAddressBook.java:44: error: return outside method return aBook.IndexOf (Address); ^

- Same, because of ';'

> .\SJAddressBook.java:47: error: cannot find symbol if (value.equalisIgnoreCase (Address.LAST)) ^ symbol: method equalisIgnoreCase (String) location: variable value of type String

- **equalsIgnoreCase** not **equalisIgnoreCase**

> .\SJAddressBook.java:48: error: return outside method return aBook.IndexOf (Address); ^

- Same, because of ';'

> .\SJAddressBook.java:53: error: return outside method return -1; ^
>                                           ; 12 errors

- Same, because of ';'

A free ide might make your life easier. [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), [intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)

Comment: I am new to this, what will eclipse do for me?  Will it help with debugging?  I am using textpad.

Comment: Yes, it will. It can be a little bit of a learning curve to begin but it has the ability to walk your code line by line with a debugger, it has syntax highlighting, auto completion, auto imports - Many of the errors for this question would be caught before even compiling. You could also try [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) If you don't want to deal with learning the ide. I believe it will give you some of the syntax highlighting.  Personally I prefer intellij the Community Edition which is free.

Comment: I guess what I'm struggling with is the constructor method, and how to define that aBook variable.  Where would I place these?